# Any caveats using [UIView new];?

Tags: ios, uiview, cgrect, designated-initializer

Being thought to basically *always* use the designated initializer I feel a bit dirty when creating new viewInstances with `[UIView new];` rather than `[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`?

Is there *any* reason *not* to this? 
Is there any practical difference at all? If you are creating a new view-instance without any frame information wouldn't the fallback to `[UIView new];` simply cut away a lot of the code-cruft? My *guess* would be that `[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];` is actually called under the hood anyways(?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[UIView new]` is a convenience method to replace `[[UIView alloc] init]` so it *is*<sup>1</sup> different to `[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]`

> Is there any reason not to this?`

In this case, I'd say "yes". You can't guarantee that `init` is equivalent to `initWithFrame:CGRectZero` in this case.

> My guess would be that ...

It's possible you are correct and the two will act identically; this isn't future proof. Implementation details like this may change.

<sup>1. *might* be different, I don't know what `initWithFrame:` does under the hood.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I recently wondered the same thing about `[UIView new]`. While using it in a new code example I ran into problems covered in Jame’s answer. These were resolved once I reverted to `[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero].` At least I know what properties the new `UIView` inherits.